# Relación Circular Base de Datos

Tags: base-de-datos, modelorelacional

Hola Espero que me ayuden, tengo una inquietud sobre esta relación. al parecer esta como relación circular, no sé si esta bien diseñada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

explico +- diseño:

*una area puede tener uno o varios grupos

*un usuario puede pertenecer a una o varias areas y tener diferentes perfiles

*un usuario puede pertencer a uno o varios grupos

*grupos pueden tener varios sub-menus

*sub-menus pertenecen a un menu

espero que me haya hecho entender gracias

Comment: Hola, Juan. ¿El programa con el que ejecutas el crebase y/o diseñas el modelo te ha reclamado que hay relaciones circulares?

Comment: En estos casos mas alla de los nombres.. es necesario saber que es cada cosa.. que es area??? que es grupos? para diseñar una db, se necesitan las reglas funcionales.

Comment: El programa donde diseñe la bd no me advirtió ningún problema @quinqui

Comment: Entonces, ¿por qué crees que las puede haber?